# Not able to create read-only user in database with SELECT privileges only

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I want to create a Postgres user that has just read-only access to the database.

I saw a similar question, but it had no resolution for my error.

I even tried searching for the error but didn't find anything useful.

Syntax:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE YourDatabaseName TO Read_Only_User;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO Read_Only_User;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO Read_Only_User;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO Read_Only_User;

# You can either grant USAGE to everyone
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO public;

# Or grant it just to your read only user
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonlyuser;
```

But none worked. I logged in as a root user.

I many times ended with the error

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation querystoresearchclient
```

Could anyone help here?

Comment: Two questions: 1) Was `querystoresearchclient` created *before* or *after* you ran those statements? 2) What do you get for `\dt+ querystoresearchclient` in `psql`? Please add the answers to the question, don't add them as a comment.

Comment: Is `readonlyuser` different to `Read_Only_User`? And is the `Read_Only_User` role really using that letter casing?